# Bash script to update GO project on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, go

guys.
I am new to bash scripting and deploying Go on ubuntu. 
I run my Go program like this

```
go build -o myprogram main.go
./myprogram &
```

But now, instead of uploading files with sftp and manually change everything I wanted to write simple bash script.

The problem is that I firstly need to kill existing process and I don't know how to get PID and kill it.

Maybe I can run my program using something different so I don't have to find PID.

I tried using ps ax | grep myprogram and then kill it, but no luck

Comment: You want to kill the process you started as `./myprogram &`?

Comment: @Inian, yes, this is one of solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` has a special variable `$!` that you can use to store the process id of the most recently started background process

```
./myprogram &
myprogram_PID=$!

kill "$myprogram_PID"
```

Comment: Thankgs that what i wanted